# Run multiple threads in parallel via command line

Tags: c#, multithreading, console

Team,

I have a C# console app which updates the eventlog.config. Now i would like to simulate the race conditions by calling the Main function with command line parameters.

So for eg if i open a **first command prompt** and point to the "application.exe" and then type application.exe -e [params] -t[params]

**open a second command prompt,** point to the same application.exe and then type application.exe -e [params] -t[params]

How do i ensure that this both runs in parallel, **so that the race conditions are simulated and i get the error as the "config file is in use"**

Comment: When you execute your app multiple times (be it within the same or different console-windows) you create different *processes* instead of *threads*. However the app might be just thread-safe but definitly not process-safe.

Comment: Semaphore can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure if I understand your question right, but if you open another console window, this means a completely new process starting. Normally this should make no difference to threads in your scenario. Ensuring to run both simultaneously is a question of timing. You might get better off starting your application only once, but using threads in it (google e. g. the Thread class) and enforce your timing with Thread.Sleep().

Comment: ok..so you mean to say..implement Threading within the console app code  and create say suppose 10 threads each calling the target function and then run only a single instance of exe within the command prompt.??

Comment: Why not? It depends, of course, on what you are really trying to achieve. For basic testing purposes of your config locking mechanism etc. this should be sufficient. But as HimBromBeere mentioned, thread- and process-safety are 2 slightly different things and you have to know, what you want. If process-safety has to be guaranteed, you should rather keep starting two consoles.

Comment: BTW you can also run commands multiple times in the background by typing "start /b Application.exe" multiple times in the console window.